# HealthVault AUTH not providing WCToken (need to access PersonInfo data)

Tags: c#, asp.net, healthvault

I am building a HealthVault web application. To preface my question, I want to clarify that I am not extending any HealthVault classes (`HealthServicePage`, `HealthServiceActionPage`, etc.) within any of my pages. Instead, I am using the static methods within `WebApplicationUtilities` to interact with HealthVault data. I am able to get to the sign in page, sign in, and get redirected to my app just fine. But I need to use the `WCToken` QueryString parameter to access the `PersonInfo` data via the `GetPersonInfo(string)` method within `WebApplicationUtilities`. The redirect URL is not returning/does not include a `WCtoken` parameter.

The return/redirect URL should be formatted as such (via HealthVault on MSDN):

https://*applicationActionURL*?target=AppAuthSuccess&wctoken=*auth_token*&instanceId=1

and mine is just

https://*applicationActionURL*?target=AppAuthSuccess&instanceId=1

Can someone help me to find a different way to access `PersonInfo` data or get the `WCToken` parameter to show up so I can use it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the request url, you can specify the "token redirection method" for the shell redirect. It should have been `get` by default, but it was setting it as `post` for some reason. Changed the trm query parameter and got my wctoken.